# Make Check Internet Async win Webclient.Openread

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My apps in xamarin form is populate by a json file i download online then i need to be sure device have internet access.

I try this but it freeze UI and timeout not seam to be used then i like to make it async.

```c#
private void CheckClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckForInternetConnection() == true)
    {
        isinternet.Text = "Internet ok";
    }
    else
    {
        isinternet.Text = "Internet down";
    }
}

public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
    
    try
    {
        using (var client = new MyWebClient(5000))
            
        using (client.OpenRead("http://google.com/generate_204"))
            return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

with this class

```c#
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
   
    private int timeout;
    public int Timeout
    {
        get
        {
            return timeout;
        }
        set
        {
            timeout = value;
        }
    }

    public MyWebClient()
    {
        this.timeout = 10000;
    }

    public MyWebClient(int timeout)
    {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) and the asynchronous methods it implements. Try to stay away from legacy HTTP client implementations such as `WebClient`.

A quick example would be:

```
private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

private async void CheckClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var isConnected = await CheckForInternetConnectionAsync();
    if(isConnected)
    {
        isinternet.Text = "Internet ok";
    }
    else
    {
        isinternet.Text = "Internet down";
    }
}

private static async Task<bool> CheckForInternetConnectionAsync()
{
    using(var tokSource = new CancellationTokenSource(5000))
    {
        try
        {
            await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.example.com", tokSource.Token);
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This will leave your UI responsive, but at the same time accomplish making a request.

Comment: Thank you very much, it s working good, just add :

catch (Exception e) { return false; }

cause it can't resolve if no internet.